# My javascript doesn't show error, but it doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this code in my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#theatreC').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: '/Inicio.html',
            data: {
                llama: teatro
            },
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function success(data) {
                $('#mainPage').html(
                    "<p>Buscando...</p>"
                );
            },
            error: function error(data) {
                $('#mainPage').html(
                    "<p>Error</p>"
                );
            }
        });
      });

});
```

and it doesn't do anything. I checked the console, but there's no error about the script. I want that, when the user clicks on the list element with id "theatreC", it writes in the  with id "mainPage". This is the header of my html file:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Fuentes/Fuentes.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Icon.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Can you check if the ajax request is being made at all? Is it failing, completing with no result, or not happening at all?

Comment: debug, debug, debug... step through the code, set breakpoints, log to the console.

Comment: being honest, I don't know how to debug

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code, and my web is hosted in hostinger

Comment: Your snippet is missing rest of the html, e.g: where is the `theatreC` element? I would also offer https://areknawo.com/javascript-debugging-done-right/ for debugging. Best of luck!

Comment: Run it in a real browser instead of VSC, and use the Network panel of DevTools to see if the AJAX request is being made.

Comment: I added console.log to any step in the script, it only goes trough "$(document).ready(function()", but it doesn't reads the click event, so, how can I create the reference to the object with the ID "theatreC"?